# any base of the canonical topology in $\mathbb R$ can be decreased

Tags: general-topology

Any base of the canonical topology in $\mathbb R$ can be decreased  .
I have found this question in Elementary Topology book. I am not quite sure what the term "decreased" mean here. 
Does it mean that for a given basis B of canonical topology, there exits another basis B' such that B' $\subset$ B.
Can anyone help me with this ?

Comment: Yes, that is what it means.

Answer (score 1):

Take a non-void element $U$ of $B$. $U$ is open. Let's show that $U$ can be written as a union of two open subsets $U=D_1 \cup D_2$, with both $D_i\ne U$. Indeed, take $x\in U$, $D_1 = U\backslash \{x\}$, and $D_2$ an open interval inside $U$ containing $x$, but not equal to $U$.
Now both $D_1$, $D_2$ are unions of some elements of $B$, and those are sests $\ne U$. Therefore, $U$ is a union of some elements in $B\backslash \{U\}$. We conclude that $B\backslash \{U\}$ is also a basis.